# How to check inside PHP function if parameter (that is passed by reference) was passed into it?

Tags: php, function, parameters

Here's an example:

```
function example(&$outDbgOutput = null)
{
    $bUseDbgOutput = 
         how_to_know_if_this_parameter_was_passed_into_this_function($outDbgOutput);
    //...
}
```

And then two types of calls:

```
example();
```

and

```
example($output);
```

PS. I'm using `PHP 7.4`

Comment: `if (isset())`?

Comment: @Mech no, that's not always correct. It will work if I did this: `$output=""; example($output);` but it won't work if I just did: `example($output);` like I showed above. In that case `isset()` will always return `false`.

Comment: `func_num_args()` is a counter function you could also use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php

Comment: `if (isset($output) && $output !== "")`

Comment: @Scuzzy yeah, that would theoretically work. The downside is that I have to keep count of parameters in that found, which is quite error prone.

Comment: @Mech: :) ok, but about this `$output=7276363464; example($output);`?

Comment: @c00000fd. That is valid output.

Comment: @Mech: in that case `isset($output) && $output !== ""` will resolve to `false`, while it should be `true` as I passed `$output` into it as in `$output=7276363464; example($output);`. You can't just hardcode it to `!== ""`. From what I've seen so far `func_num_args()` is the only method that produces reliable results, but it requires me to hard-codie the count of input parameters, which I don't really like. Thus I'm asking it here...

Comment: I don't discredit your asking. I'm learning from this.

Comment: @Mech yeah, wait until someone finds a duplicate to calling `is_null()` :)

Comment: Could `$output` be `null`? e.g. is this scenario possible `$output = null; example($output);`

Comment: @Nick Hypothetically yes. It would still be a passed input parameter, wouldn't it?

Comment: @c00000fd indeed it would. I'm not convinced there's any way to distinguish between that and the variable not being passed as (I'm pretty sure) there isn't any way to check if a variable is a reference or not. Even `debug_zval_dump` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Is the scenario possible where `$output` isn't defined but you still call `example($output)` instead of `example()`?

Answer (score 1):

Since the default value of `$outDbgOutput` is null,

```
if($outDbgOutput !== null){
 //logic
}
```

or you can use `isset()` and check if the value is not equal to null since `isset()` is not returning anything when the value that is assigned to [the variable is null](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```
 if(isset($outDbgOutput) && $outDbgOutput !== null){
     //logic
    }
```

I was reading about the function [func_num_args()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) as it was mentioned in the comment section as well.For the use of future me I'll add that in here as well.

```
if(func_num_args($outDbgOutput) > 0){
//since func_num_args will return the number of parameters that was passed
}
```

Comment: `$outDbgOutput !== null` please. Otherwise it passes for empty strings, zero, `false`...

Comment: This is wrong, or just coveres some situations. Please read my comments to the first post. .... And your second edit is also not complete.